# Why doesn't the else if part of my if statement get reached?

Tags: java

I'm writing this mini gambling game that offers multiple different games to play, and I'm working on one of the simpler ones, a simple higher lower game, but when the code reaches the part where it checks if the number that the user sees first is higher or lower to the new number, if it's not less than the original number, it skips past everything and tells the user they lost, even if they guess correctly, I'm still very new to Java, so it's probably a simple mistake.

Edited to remove the unnecessary code information and fixed the curly braces

```java
if (number > result)
{
    if (guess.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))
    {
        System.out.println("You win!");
        money += wage + 3;
        return money;
    }
} 
else if (number < result)
{
    if (guess.equalsIgnoreCase("l"))
    {
        System.out.println("You win!");
        money += wage + 3;
        return money;
    }
}
else if (number == result)
{
    if (guess.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
    {
        System.out.println("JACKPOT!!");
        money = wage * 2;
        return money;
    }
}
System.out.println("Oops, your lost.");
return money;
```

Comment: what is up with the inconsistent braces? If theres nothing wrong with the code logic, it might be due to this.

Comment: Your `else`s are pairing with the wrong `if`s.  Put the `if` bodies in curly braces (`{}`) to prevent this.

Comment: I changed my code to put `{}` around all the `if`s, however it still skips to the end if the first `if` isn't true

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger.

Comment: It prints entered for the first `if` but not the other ones, however I just realized there's a major logic error, let me fix it and see if it was just a simple `result > number` instead of `number > result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a simple logic error, it should be

```
if (result > number) else if (result < number)
```

instead of

```
if (number > result) else if (number < result)
```

The curly braces were the main thing however

Answer (score 2):

Because `else if (number < result)` is associated with the statement `if (guess.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))`.
In general it is a good practice to always use curly braces for if, for and while keywords